# Is there a writing tool that moves the text rather than the cursor?

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice

I write quite a lot for my day job. I am wondering whether there is a tool that keeps the cursor always at the same place (for instance, the middle of the screen) and move the text up/down as you write.

That would save me a lot of scrolling and it might give me a productivity boost.

Ideally the tool should be able to handle odt documents. An extension in LO would be fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you use Vim, set [`scrolloff`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_cursor_centered_vertically_on_the_screen) to a large number:

```
set scrolloff=999
```

Comment: Nice. This works for vim. Too bad vim does not handle odt files.